# Can I add the same object to two different arrays?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, object, nsarray, foundation

Is this valid:

```
 NSObject anObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
 [array1 addObject:anObject];
 [array2 addObject:anObject];
```

My money is on yes, since I'm only adding references to the same object, or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes :) Dont forget to make it a mutable array

Comment: Specifically, you'd need a mutable array for `addObject:` to work. There's not a general rule saying that arrays need to be mutable.

Comment: So, removing anObject from just one of these arrays won't make the reference from the other one invalid?

Comment: No, it just decrements the objects reference counter by 1